# How do i hook js function, prevent action beeing executed on if statement and continue function flow

Tags: javascript

```js
    const queries = ['bite', 'attack', 'curse', 'heal']

    function sendQuery(query) {
        console.log('Sending Query -> ' + query);
    }

    setInterval(() => {
        sendQuery(queries[Math.floor((Math.random() * queries.length))]);
    }, 1000);



    const _sendQuery = sendQuery;
    sendQuery = function(e) {
        if (e == 'curse') {
            //Now if it matches 'curse' i want to prevent it from being logged, without touching the function flow. I clould just return but that will stop the func.
            //So it shouldn't be logged
        }
        console.log('Hooked Query -> ' + e);
        _sendQuery(e);
    }
```

So as I mention I want to hook into the `sendQuery` func, check if the query matches my if statement if it does I don't want to log it, without affecting the function flow what I mean by that I don't want to stop that function. I know I could do return after the if statement inside the hook.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure I understand--can you simply move `console.log` into the block that checks the query against your term?

Comment: Its just an exaple in reality i don't have access to that sendQuery function i can either rewrite it, or hook it and listen for specific queries, and if there is some query i want to stop i could do it from the hook, but dunno how.

Comment: @ggorlen, I'm guessing what OP wants is really to only console.log when e != 'curse' instead of the question they are asking.

Comment: Just to be clear i want to prevent original func from sending the query to the server if it matches my statement, imagine that the console log inside original sendQuery func is a ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to run the function when the value ISN'T Curse, instead of focusing what IS curse.

```js
const queries = ['bite', 'attack', 'curse', 'heal']

function sendQuery(query) {
    console.log('Sending Query -> ' + query);
}

setInterval(() => {
    sendQuery(queries[Math.floor((Math.random() * queries.length))]);
}, 1000);



const _sendQuery = sendQuery;
sendQuery = function(e) {

    if (e != 'curse') {
        console.log('Hooked Query -> ' + e);
        _sendQuery(e);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @Hirakinuzo, sometimes the easiest solutions are the last ones people try.

Comment: and unless there's a good reason not to, it's better form to use the "!==" or "===" instead of "!=" and "=="...